# IF Statement with VLOOKUP and Count

Tags: excel, if-statement, count, excel-formula, vlookup

Here is what I want to do.  I'm basically look for orders that it is not okay to ship a partial.  So any where it says N for Partial Ok?, I would then like for it to look for any more times that the order occurs and only count it if the quantity on hand or quantity picked is less than the open quantity.

So basically.  If R29 = N, then look at D29 for reference, then look at M29 and P29 to confirm that M29 or P29 is => than N29.  If it is greater than N29 then don't count it. If it is less than N29 then count it because it is short or an incomplete line.  Please keep in Mind that D29 can appear many more times on the spreadsheet.  So I would only want to count how many times does D29 appear as an incomplete line.

[image: Help]

Comment: What result are you expecting to see for row 29 and for row 81? Also, please be precise. You mention `N` in your question but you have `No` in the picture.

Comment: I meant NO.  Sorry about that.  IN AE29 and every row down, I want it to return the number of times that the condition above was not met.

Comment: Which means what values for the rows I specified, as in if you did it manually?

Comment: For row 29 it should not count it because the open quantity is picked or on hand.  In 81 it should not count it as well because the quantity on hand is more than the open quantity.

Comment: So it should be 0? And for AE81?

Comment: That is correct.  The only time it needs to count it is when the open quantity is more than the quantity picked or quantity on hand.

Comment: You still haven't said anything about AE81... And In AE90 also. Just to confirm what you want to get.

Comment: It wouldn't count AE81 because the quantity on hand is greater than the open quantity.  AE90 should be counted because the open quantity is greater than the quantity on hand and/or the quantity picked.

Comment: So in AE90, (from the sample in the picture), you should have 1, and in AE85, it should have 1 as well because there is one HS14962 with on hand quantity below open quantity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($R$2:$R$103="No")*($D$2:$D$103=D29)*($N$2:$N$103>$M$2:$M$103)*($N$2:$N$103>$P$2:$P$103))
```

This will count rows if:

- There is "No" in the column R;
- There are other rows with the same Sales Order (col D) with;
- Both quantity picked and quantify on hand below open quantity.

I discarded the 'or' part because from your comments, it's really not an 'or' but an 'and'.